# Show all open windows in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, screen

Can someone tell me how I can get an overview of all the open windows? Like htting ctrl+s that shows all the desktops, but for the open applications?

Right now when I hit Alt+Tab it shows quite small tiles in the middle of the screen, is it possible to have all the windows fill all the screens? (Kind of like expose in OSX)

I have compiz installed, and "static application switcher" selected, but this doesn't have the result I'm looking for (and neither does "Application switcher".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> can do it but if you want to add Mouse Gestures to it, Like Gnome 3 you can do the following:

*(as pointed out in comments)*

- Install Compiz Settings Manager
- Run it, Go to Commands under General
- Set Command 0 in Edge Bindings and come back to "*Command*" tab
- Enter "xdotool key Super_L+w" in *Command Line 0*
- Install package xdotool

Comment: That seems to be it. Any idea where I could add a mouse gesture to it?

Comment: gestikk or easystroke come to mind. Never used them myself.

Comment: @Sled: You can use CompizConfig Settings Manager to add a hot corner/edge. You could also [add a launcher item](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33852/can-unity-display-a-launcher-icon-for-spread-mode).

Comment: In what category is it that I can add corners? I'm sure I passed by it earlier today, but can't find it back..

Comment: CompizConfig > General > Commands > Edge Bindings (Rider)

Comment: Best answer ever.

Comment: Any idea what the command line code is for keyboard shortcuts? I have no idea how to write one..

Comment: @Sled, Updated the answer based on Comments, thanks for awesome comments people, I myself switched back to unity, the screen space it gives you is awesome :)

Comment: `super+W` works nice, but is there any option to display labels of the listed windows too?

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/222532/17789

Answer (score 4):

**Install compizconfig-settings-manager.**

Then

scale plugin > bindings - initiate window picker or initiate window picker for all windows, choose the edge binding

Answer (score 3):

use the window symbol + W this will show all open windows

Comment: This answer was already given....

Comment: This answer works and is simpler than the one ticked. Happy for it to be repeated.

Comment: but no longer works now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution:
install xdotool

```
apt-get install xdotool
```

Open compizconfig and add a new command:

```
xdotool key Super_L+w
```

Then just select an Edge Binding and click a corner of the screen to use.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Super</kbd> to see all open windows in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, OR click on "Activities" in upper left hand corner. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to revert back. You do NOT need to press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

To see:

- A row of all open Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd> Tab
- A screen of all open Windows (along with a Search bar): <kbd>Super</kbd> S