# How to display window titles in Unity Super+W mode?

Tags: compiz

GNOME 3 displays window titles in the spread, it helps if we can't identify the window by it's thumbnail, such as many Terminal windows open. Any way to display window titles in the Super+W screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the package `compizconfig-settings-manager`, activate the plugin `Scale Addons`, go to the *Appearance* tab in the *Scale Addons* settings, open the *Window Title* area and change *Window title display* to `All windows`

Comment: Is there a way to activate this in **Ubuntu 16.04**?  The menu configuration exist in CCSM, but changing the title display between  `No display`, `Hightlighted window only` and `All windows` doesn't afect the behavior.  It only shows in the `Highlighted window`.  I have also enabled both the `Scale Addons` and the `Text` as mentioned in the second answer.  I tried it on two different computers.

Answer (score 6):

It has gotten a bit more difficult. The new procedure is:

1. Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=compizconfig-settings-manager)  [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]  and [compiz-plugins](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=compiz-plugins)  [image: Install compiz-plugins]  via the Sotware Center icons next to the package links or in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
   ```
2. Open **CompizConfig Settings Manager**

   [image: Open Compiz]
3. Search for **"Text"** and **enable** the plugin

   [image: Enable "Text"-plugin]
4. Search for **"Scale"**, **enable** and **open** the plugin

   [image: Enable "Scale"-Plugin]
5. In the **Appearance** Tab under **Window Title** select **All Windows** in the Dropdown

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the update, that it's getting more difficult.  It appears that another hurdle has been added.  Is there a new trick to getting this behavior to work with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?  Both `Scale Addons` and `Text` has been enabled.  None of the Window Title Display options affect the way the titles are displayed.