# desktop window orgnanizer

Tags: unity, screen

Suppose you open four windows. One is Geany one a browser one is LibreOffice and one is terminal. So is there any shortcut key which open four of them next together. I mean this key switch divde the screen to four parts and on every part you see one window.
 I use  unity

Comment: super + w is not what I am looking for.http://askubuntu.com/questions/46657/show-all-open-windows-in-11-04?rq=1

Comment: `Super+W` does exactly what you're describing. What doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: @hakermania no super + w  does not divide screen. What I need is see four window at the same time on the screen, but by super + w you just choose one of them. and the final result is just one window on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combos  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+numpad will move the window in focus to the corresponding locations:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>7numPad</kbd> moves the window to the upper left.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>8numPad</kbd> moves the window to the upper right.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1numPad</kbd> moves the window to the lower left.
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>3numPad</kbd> moves the window to the lower right.

Comment: I try them on my labtop but