# Overall view of opened windows

Tags: unity, workspaces, window

There is features both in windows and mac that opens a interface you can see the currently opened windows. I recently saw that feature in the GNOME workaround. Is there anything like that in the unity included in the installation itself? Or anything that can be installed through the terminal? [image: I'm looking for something like that]. Reminder, i know the workspaces tool and use it frequently with pleasure. And the alt+tab is not enough.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://askubuntu.com/questions/46657/show-all-open-windows-in-11-04

Comment: outstanding, thank you, make it an answer so i can approve it :)

Comment: Happy to help! I cannot make an answer, because it is a duplicate.